# MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE - Java Project Path included

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a small hobby project (Media Player) with JavaFx but I have ran into a file object problem. I am getting the following error from the file chooser and it is returning the wrong path:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException:
>   MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE :
>   /Users/name/Documents/projects/java/PlayFx/file:/Users/name/Downloads/Girl%20Talk%20-%20All%20Day%20(IA123)/01%20-%20Girl%20Talk%20-%20Oh%20No.mp3
>   (No such file or directory)

I can identify the problem as so:

**MP3 Location:** file:/Users/name/Downloads/Girl%20Talk%20-%20All%20Day%20(IA123)/01%20-%20Girl%20Talk%20-%20Oh%20No.mp3

**Project Location:** /Users/name/Documents/projects/java/PlayFx/

But I can't understand why the following line of code is concatenating the two together? What could be the cause for this?

```
File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
if (file != null)
{
    try
    {
        player = new Player(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
        Scene scene = new Scene(player, 720, 535, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//if
```

Comment: You didn't check `file.exists()` to make sure it actually exists on your drive. Replace the `%20` with spaces once you get the String, or else it won't locate the directory

Comment: `%20` is the operating systems way of dealing with spaces in the filename

Comment: While attempting to print all file names within a given directory, I also had the problem of the file not working. It showed `false` for both `isDirectory()` and `isFile()`. So I checked `file.exists()` and it was returning false. I print the location, and it replaced one of my spaces with `%20`. After doing `string.replaceAll("%20", " ")` before creating the file, it worked. Have you even tried it?

Comment: I tried it with no luck still. Although it replaced the files `%20` with spaces it still merges the two directory paths

Comment: The problem is that it merges the 2 paths? It seems as if you could split the paths using `file:` as the delimiter: `String[] paths = string.split("file:");` (didn't notice "file" wasn't part of the first path)

Answer (score 0):

For your code if Player class is correct you must change :

```
player = new Player(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

in

```
player = new Player(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
```

Comment: For your code you try this player = new Player(file.toURI().toURL().toString());